# JavaFX - line is thicker than should be and transparent

Tags: java, javafx

I have problem with class Line. I created that object with default settings but that line is thicker than 1 pixel and a little transparent. I was trying fix this by change opacity, stroke, strokeWidth but nothing change there. Here is picture of how it looks:

[image]

Gray line is present apperance.
Black line is expected appearance

Answer (score 0):

Please use CSS to make these changes. You can make a CSS file and write the following lines to make it as you want

```
.line {
    -fx-stroke-width: 1px;
    -fx-stroke: BLACK ;
}
```